# Key Comparison for Dictionary where compound key is a class again

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I saw at least 3 suggestions to implement custom comparison :

- Overriding `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` in a class.
- Constructor that implements `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`
- Linq extension method `Contains` that allows you to pass in a `IEqualityComparer<T>`

My question - is there need to do anything at all for standard comparison for such a compound key or it depends on a class ?

E.g. the following snippet works properly :

```
Dictionary<TariffKey, RefCusNomenclatureGroup> tariff = new Dictionary<TariffKey, RefCusNomenclatureGroup>();

// dictionary populated 
var trfKey = new TariffKey { Code = "xyz", SortKey = "123" };

if ( tariff.ContainsKey( trfKey ) ) // compared as expected - match - when both string fields are equal 
{
       //do something here
}

struct  TariffKey
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string SortKey { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You mean you **have working code**, but you're afraid you did the wrong way, because others said you should do something additional?

Answer (score 0):

My omission. Dictionary key was declared as struct. Struct is a value type. As soon as

```
struct TariffKey
```

changed to

```
public class TariffKey
```

i.e value type becomes reference type, the snippet stops working unless we specify additional equality rules described in the question.